# How do I make Apache HttpClient respect the Path in a Set-Cookie header?

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I have local server running with endpoints under `/server/public` and `/server/saml`, and I'm using HttpClient (v4.4.1) to interact with it. Requests to any endpoint trigger (if the client doesn't already have a session) the header `Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ABC123; Path=/server/`, so that the client should have one session.

However, if I debug and look at the contents of my `BasicCookieStore`, the saved cookies have the paths `/server/public` and `/server/saml`, resulting in two cookies being saved, and different session cookies being sent depending on the endpoint.

I'm using the standard `CookieSpec`, and see the same behaviour with standard strict.

Any ideas what's happening or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue was caused by [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1640) that caused `Path` headers to not be respected. Instead, the client would strip everything after the last forward slash in the URL the response was retrieved from, and use that as the cookie's path. The relevant comment from Scott Blum:

> Namely, mixed-cased cookie attributes were not being handled properly. For example, if the Set-Cookie header being parsed contained a "Path=/foo" attribute, the path would not be respected at all. This is because the attributeHandler lookup would fail (it's keyed to "path").

Upgrading httpclient to version 4.5 fixed the problem.